# Javascript - Why do these two images look different?

Tags: javascript, image

Two pieces of code and their results - which i expected to evaluate to the same thing but evidently do not - why is this the case?[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code instead of pictures of code. Also please tag with the framework you are using

Answer (score 1):

in the first case you get the first color, then you set the second color, and after the first change you get the second color.

```
redvalue = 1;
greenvalue = 2;

//your first script
greenvalue = redvalue;
redvalue = greenvalue;

//result of first script
greenvalue = 1
redvalue = 1
```

in the second case you are getting the two colors before set anything

```
redvalue = 1;
greenvalue = 2;
tempredvalue = redvalue;
tempgreenvalue = greenvalue;

//your second script
greenvalue = tempredvalue;
redvalue = tempgreenvalue;

//result of second script
greenvalue = 1
redvalue = 2
```